# How to convert many columns to one column in excel but keep the 1st cell of each column and repeat it in new rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

I have and excel document that looks like this:

[image: Input, {Male|John|Mike|George}{Female|Ann|Joan|Jane}]

and i want it to be like:

[image: Output, {Male|John}{Male|Mike}{Male|George}{Female|Ann}{Female|Joan}{Female|Jane}]

*comma (,) means that data are in different cells horizontally.

is there any vb macro or an expression to do it?

Comment: You example shows **3** names in each row.  Are there always **3** names in each row??

Comment: yes all rows have the same number of columns.

Comment: I have make an edit to add pictures for the examples

Comment: If you have Excel 2010 or later, you can use `Power Query` (a free MS addin for 2010/2013) or `Data-->Get & Transform-->From table/range` (included in 2016) to UNpivot the "name" columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all of the Rows have the same number of columns, then you can use `INDEX`, `INT`, `COUNTA` and `MOD` to break this down.

Column A:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$D$2,1+INT((ROW()-1)/(COUNTA(Sheet1!$1:$1)-1)),1)
```

Column B:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$D$2,1+INT((ROW()-1)/(COUNTA(Sheet1!$1:$1)-1)),2+MOD(ROW()-1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$1:$1)-1))
```

Where `Sheet1!$A$1:$D$2` is the 'Input' range, and `Sheet1!$1:$1` is any row in that range with a full row of data.

`INDEX` lets you get a specific row/column of a range.  Our Range is `Sheet1!$A$1:$D$2`, and the Row is the same for both formulae:

```
1+INT((ROW()-1)/(COUNTA(Sheet1!$1:$1)-1)),
```

This will be 1 for *n* rows, 2 for the next *n*, etc, where *n* is the number of cells in a row **minus** the starter column (i.e. how many names per gender)

(`INT` removes the decimal part of a number, so `INT(3/4)` is `INT(0.75)`, which is `0`.  `COUNTA` just counts the non-blank cells)

The difference between the two is the Column.  In column A, we just want the **first** column, so Column is `1`.  In column B, we want the *x*th item after the first column, where *x* A) counts up by 1 each row and B) resets to 1 when we go from Male to Female (or beyond)

Now, the `MOD` function lets us do that fairly simply:  `MOD(0, 3)` is 0, `MOD(1, 3)` is 1, `MOD(2, 3)` is 2, and `MOD(3, 3)` is back to **0**.  We just need to start out row count at 0 (subtract 1 from Row, and add it back outside the `MOD`) and remove the first column from the items-per-row (subtract 1 from the `COUNTA`, add 1 outside the `MOD`)

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward solution would be to use Split

```
Sub TransferIt()

Const SEP = ","

Dim rg As Range
Dim vdat As Variant
Dim lDat As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim col As Collection

    ' Assumption data is in column A, adjust accordingly
    Set rg = Range("A1:A4")
    vdat = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rg)

    Set col = New Collection

    For i = LBound(vdat) To UBound(vdat)
        lDat = Split(vdat(i), SEP)
        For j = LBound(lDat) + 1 To UBound(lDat)
            ' first field always contains female or male
            col.Add lDat(LBound(lDat)) & SEP & lDat(j)
        Next j
    Next i

    vdat = collectionToArray(col)

    ' Write data into column B
    Range("B1").Resize(UBound(vdat) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vdat)

End Sub

' Source: http://www.iwebthereforeiam.com/iwebthereforeiam/2004/06/excel-vba-code-to-convert-coll.html
Function collectionToArray(c As Collection) As Variant()
    Dim a() As Variant: ReDim a(0 To c.Count - 1)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        a(i - 1) = c.Item(i)
    Next
    collectionToArray = a
End Function
```

Comment: sorry if i was not clear in the question, i have edited it: *comma (,) means that data are in different cells horizontally.

Comment: @mike_x_ That confusion is why screenshots are usually prefered for data-snippets :)

Comment: Yes I assumed data were in one cell

Answer (score 0):

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Code:

```
Sub settupp()
Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
s1.Activate
n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
k = 1
For i = 1 To n
namee = Cells(i, 1).Value
For j = 2 To 4
numberr = Cells(i, j).Value
s2.Cells(k, 1) = namee
s2.Cells(k, 2) = numberr
k = k + 1
Next
Next
End Sub
```